# Split an array into two arrays based on identical values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arrayAll = [
  '156' => '1',
  '157' => '1',
  '158' => '2',
  '159' => '1',
  '160' => '2',
  '161' => '1'
];
```

where the keys are unique - they don't ever repeat. And the value could be either 1 or 2 - nothing else.

And I need to "split" this `$arrayAll` array into `$array1` - that will contain everything with value 1 and `$array2` - that will contain everything with value 2 so in the end I will have:

```
$array1 = [
  '156' => '1',
  '157' => '1',
  '159' => '1',
  '161' => '1'
];
```

and

```
$array2 = [
  '158' => '2',
  '160' => '2'
];
```

and as you can see, I will have the keys from the original array will remain the same.

What is the simplest thing to do to separate the original array like this?

Comment: Guys, all of your solutions so far are too complicated, there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Post it as an answer then. That is what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` and compare each value and assign it to a new array.

```
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];
foreach($arrayAll as $key=>$val){
    if($val == 2){
        $array2[$key] = $val;
    }else{
        $array1[$key] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cK7YH)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way.
Loop it and create a temporary array to hold the values then extract the values to your array 1 and 2.

```
Foreach($arrayAll as $k => $v){
    $res["array" . $v][$k] = $v;
}
Extract($res);

Var_dump($array1, $array2);
```

https://3v4l.org/6en6l

Updated to use extract and a method of variable variables.
The update means it will work even if there is a value "3" in the input array.

https://3v4l.org/jbvBf

Comment: You are close, but there is an even easier way ;)

Comment: Please tell me. I'm in shock. What could it possibly be?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest thing to do is to use a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
$array = [
  '156' => '1',
  '157' => '1',
  '158' => '2',
  '159' => '1',
  '160' => '2',
  '161' => '1'
];

$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    // If value is 1, add to array1
    // If value is not 1, add value to array2
    if ($value === '1')
        $array1[$key] = $value;
    else
        $array2[$key] = $value;


echo var_dump($array1);
echo '<br>';
echo var_dump($array2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use indirect reference:

```
$arrayAll = array("156"=>"1", "157"=>"1", "158"=>"2", "159"=>"1", "160"=>"2", "161"=>"1");

foreach($arrayAll as $key=>$value) {
          $name = "array".$value;
          $$name[$key] = $value;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Why a switch case? The code works without it: https://3v4l.org/QQSJo and what is `$i` doing in the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
//your array
$yourArray = [
  '156' => '1',
  '157' => '1',
  '158' => '2',
  '159' => '1',
  '160' => '2',
  '161' => '1'
];
```

With the conditions you mentioned just build two arrays, you can use array_keys with the second parameter that accepts a search value

```
 $array1 = array_keys($yourArray, '1');
 $array2 = array_keys($yourArray, '2');
```

If you don't want to use array_keys, go for an iteration

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value){
   //will always be 1 or 2, so an if-else is enought
   if($value == 1){
      $array1[] = $key;
   } else {
      $array2[] = $key;
   }
}
```

And that's it.

Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) for array_keys

If you have more than 2 values, the following will work and can be reused for other cases

You want to group them according to the values

```
$arrayOfValues = array_values($yourArray);
//this returns only the values of the array
$arrayOfUniqueValues = array_unique($arrayOfValues);
//this returns an array with the unique values, also with this u consider
//the posibility for more different values 
//also u can get the unique values array on a single line
$arrayIfUniqueValues = array_unique(array_values($yourArray));
```

The array you will return

```
$theReturn = array();
foreach($arrayOfUniqueValues as $value ){
    //what does this do?
    //for each iteration it creates a key in your return array "$theReturn"
    //and that one is always equal to the $value of one of the "Unique Values"
    //array_keys return the keys of an array, and with the second parameter
    //it acceps a search parameter, so the keys it return are the ones
    //that matches the value, so here u are getting the array already made
    $theReturn[$value] = array_keys($yourArray, $value);

}
```

The var_dump, in this case, will look like this

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      int(156)
      [1]=>
      int(157)
      [2]=>
      int(159)
      [3]=>
      int(161)
  }
     [2]=>
     array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(158)
        [1]=>
        int(160)
    }
}
```

Hope my answer helps you, I tried to organize the solutions starting with the shortest/simplest.

Edit:
I forgot you needed the key value too, at least in this solution the array is always referring to the value, like `$array1, $array2` or the `$key` references to the value as in the last solution

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution for separating an array into others based on the values involves:

1. Getting its unique values using [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).
2. Looping over these values using [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).
3. Getting the key-value pairs intersecting with the current value using [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

**Code:**

```
# Iterate over every value and intersect it with the original array.
foreach(array_unique($arrayAll) as $v) ${"array$v"} = array_intersect($arrayAll, [$v]);
```

**Advantage:**

The advantage of this answer when compared to other given answers is the fact that it uses [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to find the unique values and therefore iterates only twice instead of `n` times.

Check out a live demo [here](https://3v4l.org/Ofnbg).

Comment: I'd appreciate it, if the downvoter provided a reason for their action 

Comment: It's kinda weird, same for my answer

Comment: Indeed @FransciscoHahn. Pretty much every answer in this thread has been downvoted without an explanation...

Comment: I suspect it's the OP